# JemmyFx jar location

Tags: javafx, jemmyfx

I would like to test my JavaFX applications and i heard that JemmyFX is the right tool to do this. However, i couldn't find the Jar to download.

I tried searching online for it but i was only able to find [this](https://java.net/projects/jemmy/sources/jemmyfx13/show) page which shows that the last commit on this project was over a year ago.

I have two questions:
1- is JemmyFX released and official or not yet?
2- Where can i download the Jar of JemmyFX?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to use this link http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/tests/ for JemmyFX for JavaFX8. It was updated two weeks ago, according to the JDK8 build, which was 2 weeks ago. Download the repo, and build JemmyFX.

Comment: JemmyFX is used for JavaFX testing all the time since JavaFX 2+ creation. So, there is always exist a version of code, which works with particular JavaFX (JDK). But it could be not synced with publicly available repo.

Answer (score 2):

JemmyFX is open-sourced, to get latest version you need to download repository and build it:

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/tests/
cd tests/tools/Jemmy/JemmyFX
ant
```

To use JemmyFx you need to add next jars (they all will be in Jemmy subfolders after build):

- JemmyFX.jar
- JemmyAWTInput.jar
- JemmyCore.jar
- GlassRobot.jar
- GlassImage.jar