# Cannot Build JemmyFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, jemmy, jemmyfx

I'm trying to create a Maven project that includes all the Jemmy modules (Jemmy Core, Glass Image, Glass Robot, JemmyFx and JemmyFX browser) because when I tried to build following these instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612485/jemmyfx-jar-location) it fails telling me that the JAR files are not available.

I have obtained the sources for Jemmy Core from [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jemmy/v2/) and then a zip file of JemmyFx source [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/tests/) (as detailed on [this page](http://qaware.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/gui-tests-for-javafx.html)).

I created a Maven project with 5 modules as described above using the sources but it appears I still have some source files missing.

For example in the class `GlassIamge.java` there is the following import:

```
import org.jemmy.Dimension;
```

This isn't in any of the sources I have downloaded so far. Looking into the `build.xml` files it looks as though there could be further dependencies on other Jemmy JARs which I wasn't first aware of. For example the `build.xml` file contains:

```
<get src="${dist.url}/JemmyCore.jar" dest="${jemmy.lib.dir}"/> 
<get> src="${dist.url}/JemmyAWTInput.jar" dest="${jemmy.lib.dir}"/>
<get src="${dist.url}/JemmyBrowser.jar" dest="${jemmy.lib.dir}"/> 
<get> src="${dist.url}/JemmySupport.jar" dest="${jemmy.lib.dir}"/>
```

Which indicates a dependency on `JemmyAWTInput.jar`, `JemmyBrowser.jar` and `JemmySupport.jar`.

So my question is do I need these JARS or preferably the source code so I can fulfil the dependencies in the other modules and if so where can I get it?

Comment: I feel your pain.  Not only have the jars disappeared, but so have the sources of those jars.

Comment: I emailed the mailing list and apparently the source repositories are in the process of being moved (I maybe para-phrasing there). In the end I found that TestFx did what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I am in progress of putting the Jemmy v3 code onto code-tools OpenJDK project: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jemmy/v3/

Whoever interested, you can help me by reviewing the code I am pushing out.

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jemmy-dev/2017-November/000037.html

I would also suggest to subscribe to the jemmy-dev@openjdk.java.net alias.